# Extracting polynomial coefficients from input string

Tags: java

I wrote this code for extracting polynomial coefficients and also evaluating equation in a point, and it works. Now, I want to modify that, so the user can enter any shape of polynomial equation.

In my code you have to enter equation like this:

```
2*x^2+3*x^1+4
```

I want to change this so it accepts:

```
2*x^5+1*x+6
```

Also, if there any terms with the same power, their coefficients must be added together.

Here is my code in java:

```java
package Priest;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Equation {

    private String Eq;
    private final String[] C;
    private int Deg;
    private final String EqHolder;

    public Equation(String Equation) {
        this.Eq = Equation;
        EqHolder = Equation;
        Eq = Eq.replaceAll("[^0-9\\-\\.]+", " ");
        Eq = Eq.replaceAll("-", " -");
        this.C = Eq.split(" ");
    }

    public String SourceEquation() {
        return EqHolder.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\*", "").replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "\\*(X)").replaceAll("\\+", "\\ + ").replaceAll("\\-", "\\ - ");
    }

    public List<BigDecimal> CaptureCoeff() {
        getDegree();
        List<BigDecimal> Temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String S : C) {
            Temp.add(new BigDecimal(S));
        }
        int Location = Temp.indexOf(BigDecimal.valueOf(Deg));
        List<BigDecimal> Coeffs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int Counter = Location - 1; Counter < Temp.size(); Counter += 2) {
            Coeffs.add(Temp.get(Counter));
        }
        return Coeffs;
    }

    public int getDegree() {
        int Degree = 0;
        for (int Counter = 0; Counter < C.length; Counter += 2) {
            if ((new Double(C[Counter])) != 0) {
                Degree = new Integer(C[Counter + 1]);
                this.Deg = Degree;
                break;
            }
        }
        return Degree;
    }

    public BigDecimal Evaluate(List<BigDecimal> Coefficients, double EvalPoint) {
        BigDecimal Output = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (int Index = 0; Index < Coefficients.size(); Index++) {
            Output = Output.add(Coefficients.get(Index).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(EvalPoint).pow(Deg--)));
        }
        return Output;
    }
}
```

And main class:

```java
package Priest;

import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long Start = System.nanoTime();
        String Str = "3.1415x^5-12.6x^4+6x^3+12*x^2-6*x^1-0";
        Equation E = new Equation(Str);
        System.out.println("Equation is: " + E.SourceEquation());
        System.out.println("Coefficients :" + E.CaptureCoeff());
        System.out.println("Polynomial Degree: " + E.getDegree());
        double Target = 47.784;
        System.out.println("Equation @ (X:" + Target + ")= " + E.Evaluate(E.CaptureCoeff(), Target).setScale(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time: " + String.format("%.20G", (System.nanoTime() - Start) / 1.0e6) + " ms.");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
run:
Equation is: 3.1415*(X)^5 - 12.6*(X)^4 + 6*(X)^3 + 12*(X)^2 - 6*(X)^1 - 0
Coefficients :[3.1415, -12.6, 6, 12, -6, 0]
Polynomial Degree: 5
Equation @ (X:47.784)= 717609084.382589022327914
Elapsed Time: 32.306242000000000000 ms.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What is the difference between 2*x^5+1*x+6 and 2*x^2+3*x^1+4 in polynomial shape? Is it the fact that you had to specify x^1 instead of x

Comment: One easy way to solve this is to pre - process the text by adding the missing values because 2*x^5 + 1*x + 6 is equivalent to 2*x^5 + 0*x^4 + 0*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 1*x + 6 therefore if you pre - process the user's input this way you won't have to change anything to your main logic and it will work fine

Comment: the difference is in  2*x^5+1*x+6  ,we have no term such x^4 or x^3 ... and in my code this is a problem,because i can't pas that equation to Equation Class specifically the     CaptureCoeff()     method.any idea?

Comment: could you give me an example about pre-process input string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go with the following equation `String Str2 = "3.1415x^5+6x^2+12*x-5";`
Here is the code that I have added upon your code in order to preprocess this equation and made it compatible to your actual logic so that It will treat it without any major change to your code.

To be totally accurate I had to change the following in your equation class:

```
public List<BigDecimal> CaptureCoeff() {
    getDegree();
    List<BigDecimal> Temp = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    for (String S : C) {
        if (! "".equals(S.trim())) {
            Temp.add(new BigDecimal(S));
        }
    }
```

So I have added the control to check that none of these S strings is trim - empty.

Here is my preprocessing code.

I have added a method called **powerSplitt** that allows to splitt the equation on the basis of the '^' char.

Then I created another method called **generateNullCoeffPolynomeWithDegree** that generate a monome in the form 0*X^k. And a similar one that generate all the similar intermediate monomes between the greater power and the lesser power

Example: 
    String str3 = generateAllNullCoeffPolynomesWithDegreeExclusiveBetween(5, 2);
    System.out.println("all poly = " + str3);

will generate: all poly = 0*x^4+0*x^3

Then I created a **buildPreProcessedPolynome** that takes the initial equation and pre process it to produce one with the null monomes inside of it. And then I just gave it to your equation program and it could process it fine!!!

Here is the code and a call example all done in the MainClass

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

```
private static List<String> workList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void powerSplitt(String equationText) {

    char[] charsList = equationText.toCharArray();

    boolean foundTargetChar = false;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < charsList.length; i++) {
        index = i;
        if (charsList[i] == '^') {

            foundTargetChar = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundTargetChar) {

        workList.add(equationText.substring(0, index));
        if (index +1 < equationText.length()) {
            powerSplitt(equationText.substring(index+1));
        } else {
            workList.add(equationText);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        workList.add(equationText);
    }

}


public static String generateNullCoeffPolynomeWithDegree(int degree) {
    return "0*x^" + degree;
}

public static String generateAllNullCoeffPolynomesWithDegreeExclusiveBetween(int startDegree, int endDegree) {
    if (startDegree-endDegree <= 1) {
        return "";
    }

    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = startDegree -1; i > endDegree; i--) {
        if (index > 0) {
            builder.append("+");
        }
        builder.append(generateNullCoeffPolynomeWithDegree(i));
        index++;
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public static String buildPreProcessedPolynome(String initialEquationText) {
    workList.clear();
    powerSplitt(initialEquationText);


    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    assert workList.size() >= 3;
    resultBuilder.append(workList.get(0));

    for (int i = 1; i <= workList.size()-2; i++) {
        int actualPower = Integer.parseInt( workList.get(i).substring(0,1));

        int nextFoundPower = Integer.parseInt( workList.get(i+1).substring(0,1));
        System.out.print("actual power = " + actualPower + " and next power = " + nextFoundPower);
        System.out.println();

        String additionalPolyParts = generateAllNullCoeffPolynomesWithDegreeExclusiveBetween(actualPower, nextFoundPower);
        resultBuilder.append("^" + actualPower);
        resultBuilder.append("+");
        resultBuilder.append(additionalPolyParts);
        resultBuilder.append(workList.get(i).substring(1));

    }

    resultBuilder.append("^" + workList.get(workList.size()-1));
    return resultBuilder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    workList.clear();

    String Str2 = "3.1415x^5+6x^2+12*x-5";

    powerSplitt(Str2);

    for (String part: workList) {
        System.out.println("PART:"  + part);
    }

    System.out.println("-----------------");

    long Start = System.nanoTime();

    String str3 = generateAllNullCoeffPolynomesWithDegreeExclusiveBetween(5, 2);
    System.out.println("all poly = " + str3);

    String preprocessed = buildPreProcessedPolynome(Str2);
    System.out.println("preprocessed = " + preprocessed);

    System.out.println();

    Equation E = new Equation(preprocessed);
    System.out.println("Equation is: " + E.SourceEquation());
    System.out.println("Coefficients :" + E.CaptureCoeff());
    System.out.println("Polynomial Degree: " + E.getDegree());
    double Target = 47.784;
    System.out.println("Equation @ (X:" + Target + ")= " + E.Evaluate(E.CaptureCoeff(), Target).setScale(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    System.out.println("Elapsed Time: " + String.format("%.20G", (System.nanoTime() - Start) / 1.0e6) + " ms.");
}
```

}

And here is the produced results (I haved added some System.out.println to check the results of my methods calls. I just noticed I have to take into account the last constant as a monome of type K*X^0, but I will leave that to you):

> PART:3.1415x
>   PART:5+6x
>
> ### PART:2+12*x-5
>
> all poly = 0*x^4+0*x^3
>   actual power = 5 and next power = 2
>   preprocessed = 3.1415x^5+0*x^4+0*x^3+6x^2+12*x-5
>
> Equation is: 3.1415*(X)^5 + 0*(X)^4 + 0*(X)^3 + 6*(X)^2 + 12*(X) - 5
>   Coefficients :[3.1415, 0, 0, 6, 12]
>   Polynomial Degree: 5
>   Equation @ (X:47.784)= 782631805.485054892561514
>   Elapsed Time: 18,441978000000000000 ms.

Comment: i like your idea but the problem still there is that you cannot enter equation like this: 2x^5+3x^3+2x. the coefficients of terms with powers 4 and 2 are absent now.

Comment: The pre - processor should be able to process that one too, since 2x^5+3x^3+2x is the same as 2x^5 + 0x^4 +3x^3 + 0x^2 +2x^1 + 0x^0. If the actual version is missing it then you can improve it a little bit and it will work fine